# Fortran subroutine hung up on OPEN statement

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I've recently started working on an existing Fortran program, and picking up the language at the same time. I wrote the following subroutine:

```
subroutine timing(yyyy, mm, dd, var, ntime, time_blocks, 
 *  time_day)

use myglobals

! ---------------------------------------------------------------------
!     Common Variables
! ---------------------------------------------------------------------    

    integer yyyy,       ! year
   *         mm,    ! month
   *         dd,    ! day
   *         ntime  ! nr of blocks for which time was measured

    real time_blocks(ntime),    
   *        time_day    
    character*4 var 

! ---------------------------------------------------------------------
!     Internal Variables
! ---------------------------------------------------------------------   

    integer ios
    integer out_unit=52

        open(unit=out_unit, file=diroutput(1:69)//'timing',
     * err=450, iostat=ios)
    450 print*, "iostat= ", iostat
    print*, "open"

    write(out_unit, format_str) yyyy, mm, dd, var, time_blocks, 
     *   time_day

    return
    end
```

The purpose of this subroutine is to write the inputs it gets from another part of the program to a file, following a defined format (format definition not included in my example). The file must be created on the first call of this subroutine, then accessed on each further call in order to append the new information. `diroutput` is a character string defined in `myglobals`.

My problem is that the program seems to get hung up at the `OPEN` statement, i.e. nothing happens until I kill the process. I ran the code with several `print*,` statements to locate the error, and found out this way that the error must be in the `OPEN` statement. It seems strange that the program does nothing at all, not even jump to the error label.

As I'm new to Fortran I might be missing something fairly obvious, so a quick look by someone more experienced might help. I'm certain that `diroutput` contains a valid path.

I'm using Linux (CentOS 5.5) and I compiled my program with Intel Fortran Compiler 11.1.

Comment: Do you know that `diroutput` has precisely 69 characters?  Perhaps use `trim (diroutput)`.  I suggest learning Fortran 95/2003 instead of FORTRAN 77.  In particularly, as mentioned by High Performance Mark, free source form is easier.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features

Comment: you should be printing ios, not iostat. is format_str in myglobals?.  The err=450 actually does nothing since you will get to that line regardless of an error.  Nono of this should cause it to hang though.

Comment: @M.S.B. thanks for the tip, I think I'll definitely use the newer versions of Fortran from now on. `diroutput` contains my path plus some additional characters, so this was the only way I found to get the path. It gives me the correct path though. Thanks @george for spotting my other mistakes. `format_str` was actually defined in this subroutine, I took it out to simplify my example and forgot to change it on that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems, from the continuation characters in (generally) column 6, to be written in fixed-form despite containing features of Fortran 90.  If it is fixed-form then statement labels, such as `450` should be in columns 1 to 5. I don't immediately see why that would cause the program to hang rather than crash, but I suggest you fix this and try again.

Comment: I still can't put my finger on what exactly caused the problem, but it may have been a form issue, as saving my file as .f90 and modifying it accordingly did the trick. The position of `450` was correct though, I just forgot to adjust the format when I copy-pasted my code - sorry about that.